# Выявите в следующем тексте гипотезу/ы (если таковые имеются), а также различные способы правдоподобных рассуждений

Tags: недопустимая-метка

**Выявите в следующем тексте гипотезу/ы (если таковые имеются), а также различные способы правдоподобных рассуждений, которые используются авторами для получения гипотезы или получения следствий из неё. Если в рассуждениях допущены ошибки, укажите их.**

**Альтруизм общественных насекомых поддерживается полицейскими методами**

Германские энтомологи из берлинского Института передовых исследований (InstituteforAdvancedStudy) показали, что альтруистическое поведение у пчел и ос является не добровольным, а вынужденным. Рабочие особи воздерживаются от откладывания собственных яиц не потому, что им выгоднее заботиться о потомстве царицы, чем о своем собственном, а потому, что их яйца уничтожаются товарищами по гнезду. Рабочие особи перепончатокрылых насекомых (ос, пчел, муравьев) обычно не размножаются, посвящая себя заботам о потомстве царицы. Альтруизм перепончатокрылых принято объяснять тем, что рабочим выгоднее заботиться о своих сестрах, чем о собственных детях. Всё дело тут в особенностях наследования пола в этом отряде насекомых. У перепончатокрылых самки имеют двойной набор хромосом и развиваются из оплодотворенных яиц. Самцы же гаплоидны (имеют одинарный набор хромосом) и развиваются партеногенетически, то есть из неоплодотворенных яиц. Из-за этого складывается парадоксальная ситуация: сестры оказываются более близкими родственницами, чем мать и дочь. У большинства животных степень родства между сестрами и между матерями и дочерьми одинакова (50% общих генов). У перепончатокрылых родные сестры имеют 75% общих генов, поскольку каждая из них получает от отца-трутня не случайно выбранную половину его хромосом, а весь геном полностью. Мать и дочь у перепончатокрылых имеют, как и у других животных, лишь 50% общих генов. Вот и получается, что для эффективной передачи своих генов следующим поколениям перепончатокрылым выгоднее заботиться о сестрах, чем о дочерях. Это обстоятельство считается главной причиной того, что именно в отряде перепончатокрылых (а не у жуков, мух или бабочек) развилась социальность, неразрывно связанная с альтруистическим отказом от размножения большинства особей.

Вместе с тем известно, что у многих видов рабочие особи физиологически вполне способны к размножению, и иногда они действительно проявляют «эгоизм», откладывая собственные яйца. Однако эти яйца часто уничтожаются другими рабочими, которые в этом случае выполняют функцию своеобразной «полиции нравов».

Германские энтомологи решили проверить, какой из двух факторов важнее для поддержания альтруизма в обществе насекомых – добровольное следование принципу «разумного эгоизма» или полицейский надзор. Для этого они собрали и обработали данные по 10 видам перепончатокрылых (9 видов ос и медоносная пчела). Оказалось, что чем строже «полиция нравов», тем реже рабочие совершают акты «эгоизма», откладывая собственные яйца.

Ученые проверили также влияние степени родства между рабочими в гнезде на альтруистическое поведение. Степень родства между ними в действительности часто бывает ниже идеальных 75%, поскольку царица может в течение жизни спариваться с несколькими разными самцами. Выяснилось, что чем ниже степень родства между сестрами-рабочими, тем сильнее полицейский надзор, и тем реже рабочие ведут себя эгоистически. Это, как легко заметить, соответствует гипотезе 2 и противоречит гипотезе 1. При низкой степени родства между рабочими им становится выгоднее уничтожать яйца других рабочих. Низкая степень родства также делает более выгодным «эгоистическое» поведение, но, как видно из полученных результатов, первый фактор явно перевешивает второй.

Авторы делают вывод, что особенности механизма наследования пола у перепончатокрылых, по-видимому, сыграли важную роль в становлении альтруистического поведения и социальности, однако у современных общественных видов альтруизм поддерживается в основном не личной выгодой, получаемой рабочими от такого поведения, а жестким полицейским контролем.

Авторы замечают, что обнаруженная ими закономерность может быть справедлива и для человеческого общества, хоть это и трудно проверить экспериментально. Общественная жизнь невозможна без альтруизма (индивид должен жертвовать своими интересами ради общества), и в конечном счете от этого выигрывают все. Однако каждой отдельной личности во многих случаях все-таки выгодно поступать эгоистически, преследуя свои корыстные интересы в ущерб коллективу. И эффективно бороться с этим можно, к сожалению, только насильственными методами.

Можно ли создать общественное устройство, где альтруизм будет полностью добровольным и выгодным каждому индивиду? Ни людям, ни насекомым это пока не удалось.